# How to deploy arduino ide code to Android app?

Tags: android, arduino-uno

I want to make my arduino UNO  pin 13 to be high when user clicks on button. I have used arduino blink template .program runs fine from my computer. But I want this program to work on Android phones too. Is there any way to do this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Im not sure I understand the question.  Arduino code is a subset of C, whereas Android code is all Java.  Not to mention Android doesn't have IO pins

Comment: @JPeroutek  I want my Android app to  perform blink action when I click on the button. So I can control my arduino from Android phone

Comment: You need to connect your Arduino with Android through some media: BlueTooth, WiFi, USB, ... I personally use BlueTooth. Ising a costless (5 euro) BlueTooth shield (HC-06 compatible, Joy MCU)

Comment: @JPeroutek - Just to point out, Android has an [`android.net class`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible this way. You can't run arduino code on Android, However you can code android app to communicate with arduino through USB or Bluetooth.
To do this you will need arduino shield, or USB OTG cable and USB TTL converter.

In my app I use usb, so here is basic example what you have to do:

1. Download some serial usb library, I use this one:
   http://felhr85.net/2014/11/11/usbserial-a-serial-port-driver-library-for-android-v2-0/
2. You need android device that supports USB OTG and USB OTG cable.
3. Connect USB to ttl converter using usb otg to android
4. Connect usb to ttl converter to arduinos serial port(**must be hardware serial and must connect GNDs**).
5. Run the app and send some data.
6. Receive data on arduino and do your action

Edit://
It is probably easier to do with some arduino shield designed to communicate with Android, however I didn't use such shield, because I needed qucik and cheap solution.

Comment: So what actually I need to do?